# Small live-cd image with openssl support

Tags: linux, openssl, livecd, certificate-authority

I'm looking for a Linux live-cd image with openssl installed.
I do not want a graphical interface and the image must be as small as possible (< 500MB).
The purpose is to build a certificate authority.

Comment: Try [PuppyLinux](http://puppylinux.com/). You can install it on a USB pendrive.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Alpine](https://alpinelinux.org)?  The standard edition (which which does not include OpenSSL, but allows it to be installed trivially with `apk add openssl`) is roughly 110MB for 64-bit x86, and the extended edition is about 300MB (which does include OpenSSL according to the package list [here](https://github.com/alpinelinux/alpine-iso/blob/master/alpine-extended.packages)).  IF you're just looking for a bare-bones system with a known state, Alpine is probably one of your best pre-built options.

If you're willing to do a bit more work, it would not be hard to put something together yourself with [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/).  I've actually used that for similar one-sff stuff, and it's pretty easy to get a basic system that takes up less than 50MB.

One word of caution though, be careful using such a system for a CA.  The known and verified boot state is nice, but you're probably going to be starved for entropy at least initially unless you're running on a recent Intel CPU (AMD still doesn't have RDRAND or RDSEED yet) or manually inject entropy.

Comment: I had already checked Alpine, seems very good, but it does not provide openssl, even in the extended version. For the entropy, I did not though about it, is it gonna be even worse with QEMU?

Comment: Huh, I could have sworn that Alpine included openssl.  FWIW, it's pretty trivial to install (`apk add openssl`), and Alpine does support installing new packages in the LiveCD environment (and the result is 100% reproducible).  As far as entropy and QEMU, there is a VirtIO RNG device you can add to the VM to pass through the host's /dev/urandom as an entropy source, but it's kind of complicated to configure.

Comment: I know but I do not want to have to install packages

Comment: Also, the extended edition does have OpenSSL (just cross verified with their upstream package list and a downloaded copy).

Comment: This is weird, I just ran the image with QEMU and tried running it

Comment: Did you have the basic version or the extended one?

Comment: Well the extended one. I'm gonna try again.

Comment: I just tried again, openssl is not in alpine extended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64294/discussion-between-l-dupre-bertoni-and-austin-hemmelgarn).

Answer (score 0):

[Devuan](https://devuan.org/index.html) has a minimal live-cd with openssl (~300MB).